# How can I get table name as column from the current table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to find a way to get the "table name" as column from the current table in SQL Server 2012

```
SELECT 
    'School1.dbo.Person', Age, COUNT(Age) 
FROM 
    School1.dbo.Person
GROUP BY 
    Age

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    'School2.dbo.Person', Age, COUNT(Age) 
FROM 
    School2.dbo.Person
GROUP BY 
    Age
```

As I'm hard-coding the table name in first column of each select statement, it doesn't make much sense, is there way I could get the table name in first column dynamically?

Appreciate your thoughts!

RAP

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your current approach -- don't think there's a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

What do you think about passing table names as variables?
Look a this quick example (I didn't try to run it).

```
    declare @tableName1 varchar(max) = 'School1.dbo.Person';
    declare @tableName2 varchar(max) = 'School2.dbo.Person';

    declare @sql1 nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT ''' + @tableName1 + ''', Age, COUNT(Age) FROM ' + @tableName1 + ' GROUP BY Age';
    declare @sql2 nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT ''' + @tableName2 + ''', Age, COUNT(Age) FROM ' + @tableName2 + ' GROUP BY Age';

    declare @table1 as table(tabName varchar(max), Age int, AgeCount int);
    declare @table2 as table(tabName varchar(max), Age int, AgeCount int);

    insert into @table1 execute sp_executesql @sql1;
    insert into @table2 execute sp_executesql @sql2;

    select * from @table1
    union all
    select * from @table2
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show you all your field names in all your tables in your database.

```
USE your_DB
GO
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%ticker%'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```